# Is the Hulu series Hit-Monkey a standalone production?

Tags: hit-monkey

Is Hulu TV series [*Hit-Monkey*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hit-Monkey_(TV_series)) (2021) a standalone production, or does it tie into the canon of any other Marvel productions?

Looking for an official source, such as interviews as a preferred source, not simply conjecture based on shared characters.

Answer (score 6):

*Hit Monkey* and *M.O.D.O.K.* are considered to be set in [Earth-1226](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Earth-1226), which was originally going to include *Howard the Duck*, *Tigra & Dazzler*, and a crossover series titled *The Offenders* before they were cancelled. As far as I can tell, the only indication in the shows that they share the same universe is a news ticker in the 6th episode of *Hit Monkey* referencing that GRUMBL acquired AIM from M.O.D.O.K..

From [a comicbook.com article](https://comicbook.com/marvel/news/is-new-modok-show-in-mcu-marvel-studios/), Jordan Blum's statement on *M.O.D.O.K.*'s universe:

> "Yeah, we're our own universe. I think like, you know, Harley Quinn is a good example of like, that's not the movies, but it's really cool actually," the writer says. "Marvel has like a database of all the universes in the multiverse, and there's a guy who runs it and they let me pick the numbering of our universe. My son's birthday, 12/26, is our universe, so we were in the Marvel Multiverse, which is awesome."
>
> So there you have it — MODOK exists on Earth-1226, far from the MCU's Earth-199999. Other universes of note include Earth-616 — the main continuity used by the Marvel comics lore — and Earth-1610, the world previously inhabited by comic publisher's "Ultimate" universe.

As noted above, I haven't found any interview statement about *Hit Monkey*, but it does include a reference to the events of *M.O.D.O.K.*.